# Post json with rest sharp

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, rest, post

I  need to post data to a wcf service with a wp7. After a quick look i found rest sharp and a lot of tuto to use it in "get" mode.

But I can't find a solution to post data to my service.

```
var client = new RestClient(Global.Url + "/user");
var request = new RestRequest("resource", Method.POST);

client.ExecuteAsync<Resource>(request, (response) =>
{
    var resource = response.Data;
});
```

That's what I found in the rest sharp website. But I do not understand what the "Ressource" is.

Comment: Resource is where you put, /user ,so you can have a base URL on the client and different resurce calls or requests.

Comment: then if just need to contact "/user", i sould remplace "resource" by "/user" and remove it from the client ?

Comment: Are you using fiddler?  Get that, it makes debugging this stuff easier.  But yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Thx, with changing var client = new RestClient(Global.Url + "/user");
                var request = new RestRequest("resource", Method.POST); to var client = new RestClient(Global.Url);
                var request = new RestRequest("/user", Method.POST); it's working

Comment: http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"resource" is a name of the method called on a server, i.e. `Global.Url + "/user/resource?some_parameter=value`